# An exception was thrown by the type initializer for Newtonsoft.Json.Utilities.ConvertUtils on Ubuntu

Tags: .net, linux, ubuntu, json.net

Our app uses JSON.net just fine on Windows. On Linux (we're testing in Ubuntu) we get an exception:

```
    An exception was thrown by the type initializer for Newtonsoft.Json.Utilities.ConvertUtils
    20150310_11:51:37.404 ERROR  :    at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.DefaultContractResolver.IsJsonPrimitiveType(System.Type t)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.DefaultContractResolver.CreateContract(System.Type objectType)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.DefaultContractResolver.ResolveContract(System.Type type)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.GetContractSafe(System.Type type)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.Deserialize(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader reader, System.Type objectType, Boolean checkAdditionalContent)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.DeserializeInternal(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader reader, System.Type objectType)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader reader, System.Type objectType)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(System.String value, System.Type type, Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializerSettings settings)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(System.String value, Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializerSettings settings)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(System.String value)
```

The InnerException was

```
Could not load file or assembly 'System.Numerics, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' or one of its dependencies.
```

On other spots online, they said it could be that we needed to install "libmono-system-numerics4.0-cil" but apt-get shows that to be installed already and up-to-date.

We're using .NET 4.0 (because we want to stay compatible with Windows XP, the market share is still significant).

Any ideas on how to get it running?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For whatever reason, it just doesn't want to cooperate with the version installed on Linux & can never load it.

Here's what I did that eventually led it to run:

- Added System.Numerics reference to the project that uses JSON.net
- Grabbed the System.Numerics.dll from the Windows distribution that worked (this is probably a .NET assembly instead of Mono) and added that to my build process in such a way that the System.Numerics.dll ends up in the /bin/Release directory of the Linux project (the same directory as the .exe for the main app).